# numpy: create deque from ndarray which is an array of arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, deque

I have a numpy ndarray in this form:

```
inputs = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
```

How can I convert this `ndarray` to a `deque` (`collections.deque`) so that the structure get preserved (array of arrays) and I could apply normal deque methods such as `popleft()` and `append()`? for example:

```
inputs.popleft()
->>> [[2],[3]]

inputs.append([4])
->>> [[2],[3], [4]]
```

Comment: To be picky `inputs` is a 2d array, shape (3,1).  We don't normally describe it as an array of arrays.  Admittedly when you iterate on it, you do get 1 element arrays.  `inputs.tolist()` is a pure nested list.  `list(inputs)` is a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I think that you can do:

```
inputs = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
inputs = collections.deque([list(i) for i in inputs])
inputs.append([4])
inputs.popleft()
```

EDIT.
I edited code

Comment: `inputs = np.array([1],[2],[3])` results in: `ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted`

Answer (score 2):

I think you could pass `inputs` directly to `deque`

```
from collections import deque

i = deque(inputs)

In [1050]: i
Out[1050]: deque([array([1]), array([2]), array([3])])

In [1051]: i.popleft()
Out[1051]: array([1])

In [1052]: i
Out[1052]: deque([array([2]), array([3])])

In [1053]: i.append([4])

In [1054]: i
Out[1054]: deque([array([2]), array([3]), [4]])
```

Later on, when you want `numpy.array` back, just pass deque back to numpy

```
np.array(i)

Out[1062]:
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```